# Let G be a locally compact group, and let U be an open set in G. Show that Ug is an open set in G for all g in G.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. Let $U \subseteq G$ be open. Show that $Ug \subseteq G$ is open for all $g \in G$.

I'm really not sure how to prove this. I think it will involve the condition on a topology that any union of open sets is open, and any finite intersection of open sets is open, but I don't know how to express $Ug$ as a union/intersection of open sets in $G$. I would appreciate a hint!

Comment: By the assumtions of being a topological group, the right-multiplication by group elements  $R_g:G\rightarrow G$ is assumed to be continous. Since it has a continous inverse, it must be a homeomorphism. Therefore it maps open sets to open sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In a topological group operations are continuous. In particular, $t_g:G\rightarrow G$ given by $t_g(x) = xg$ is continuous. Similarly with $t_{g^{-1}}$. Next 
$$t_g\cdot t_{g^{-1}}=?,\,t_{g^{-1}}\cdot t_g = ?$$

**Remark.**
You don't need local compactness.

Comment: isn't t_{g}.t_{g^{-1}} just the identity function?

Comment: @Chris Yes. How do we call continuous function with continuous inverse? Btw. you've got full answer along this lines written by Henno Brandsma (I don't get why people are duplicating answers here)

Comment: Ah I see, it's a homeomorphism of course, hence it preserves openness

Comment: @Chris exactly.

Comment: Simultaneous typing is invisible.... Your answer just appeared earlier.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh, I see. This has happened to me either and then I decided to delete my answer.

Comment: I only delete when it's wrong.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The map $f_g: G \to G$ defined by $f_g(x)=xg$ is a homeomorphism:

- continuous as multiplication $G \times G \to G$ is continuous and we just restrict to second element to $g$.
- Its inverse is of the same form $f_{g'}$ with $g'=g^{-1}$ by simple group laws.

So $f_g$ is an open map and so $f_g[U]=Ug$ is open for any open $U \subseteq G$. This is all true in any topological group.